# Why is dotnet run completely different than VS Code debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have started a few unmodified projects using `dotnet new -t web`. I have tried to restore using VS Code v 1.8.1 and `dotnet restore`. From the tutorials I have followed on dot.net and mva.microsoft.com there shouldn't be any difference in the projects at that point. I think that's right and I have not modified the project in question. When I run the same fresh project in the same browser using `dotnet run` then open a browser the left side of the image is the result as expected. When I try to run using F5 or pressing the run button on VS Code then the right side of the image is the result. All the practice I have had watching Elmo with my daughter has helped me come to the conclusion that one of these things is not like the other.

The proximate cause is that VS Code runs the site without a valid reference to necessary resources like the Bootstrap CSS file. Incorrectly, VS Code references Bootstrap at `http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`, while running the project with `dotnet run` is more fruitful and uses the following external URL: `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Is this a bug that will be fixed eventually and is there some documentation that would help fix this?

[image]

From the looks of the .vscode folder and the comment so far, the tasks.json file seems to be a key difference. Here is the file content:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\project.json"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.0\\Avalon.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Go to .vscode folder and analyze the debug settings there. If you don't know what should be the right ones, post the current file contents as part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did have the same issue.

The workaround is as follows:

Either run:

### bower install

For this you need to install nodejs and git

Install Node.js from `https://nodejs.org/`
Install git from `https://git-scm.com/`

npm install -g bower
bower install

### Or open _Layout.cshtml, and change line 9 to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Please have a look at the deeper explanation to this problem explained here:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4076

Regards,
Thomas